# how I play .Wav sound in IE7,IE8,Safari and other supported browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, playback

I need to playing .Wav sound after success some stuff.I tried this one but its not working in IE7,IE8 and Safari whats wrong here?

```
var currentFile = "";
function playAudio() {
        var oAudio = document.getElementById('myaudio');

        // See if we already loaded this audio file.
        if (jQuery("#audiofile").val() !== currentFile) {

            oAudio.src = jQuery("#audiofile").val();
            currentFile = jQuery("#audiofile").val();

        }

            var test = jQuery("#myaudio");
            test.src = jQuery("#audiofile").val();
            oAudio.play();   
    }


    if (Modernizr.audio) {
            if (Modernizr.audio.wav) {
               jQuery("#audiofile").val("sound/smw_save_menu.wav"); 

            }
            if (Modernizr.audio.mp3) {
                jQuery("#audiofile").val("sound/mario_coin.mp3");

            }
        }
        else {
          jQuery("#HTML5Audio").hide();
          jQuery("#OldSound").html('<embed src="sound/smw_save_menu.wav" autostart=false width=1 height=1 id="LegacySound" enablejavascript="true" >');

        }
```

I need to playing .Wav sound after success some stuff.I tried this one but its not working in IE7,IE8 and Safari whats wrong here?

Comment: Give me any supported code if you have better than this

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking the HTML that goes into your `#OldSound` container needs to be closer to something like this:

```
var flashAudioHTML =
'<object data="sound/smw_save_menu.wav"  width="1" height="1" other_attrs...>' +
    '<embed src="sound/smw_save_menu.wav" width="1" height="1" other_attrs...>' +
'</object>';
jQuery("#OldSound").html( flashAudioHTML );
```

Comment: For more programmatic control over creating Flash elements via JavaScript, check out the [SWFObject library](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/).

Comment: sorry @Impirator its not working sounds are not playing i am using your code :(

Comment: Any reason why you have `autostart="false"`?  Wouldn't you want the sound to play as soon as the Flash object was created and loaded?  Or are you telling it to start some other way?

Comment: i do again autostart="True" but same things are going on